# Can't change UIView.isHidden property after action is called by UIBarButton

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using `UIView`'s `isHidden` property to show/hide controls on a posting interface I'm developing. I use this to change the controls available when the keyboard is up/down, post types are selected, etc. I have written a method triggered by notifications that sets the view properties (mainly `.isHidden`) and animates changes, which is called when the keyboard appears, or when the user selects a post type which then changes the controls available to them. This usually works perfectly fine, and the properties change as intended, but when the method is triggered by a `UIBarButton` action, the view being set to visible becomes unresponsive. After hitting bar button I am unable to change the `isHidden` property of the view (even by explicitly setting `isHidden` to true or false... it does not change).

Here is the method that changes the view properties:

```swift
@objc func animateActionViewChange(_ sender: Notification) {
        // DEBUG
        print("\n[BEFORE]\nnormalActionView.isHidden: \(normalActionView.isHidden)\nkeyboardActionView.isHidden: \(keyboardActionView.isHidden)\nkeyboardUp: \(keyboardUp)\nactionViewActive: \(actionViewActive)")

        // save prev state
        let normalTemp: Bool = normalActionView.isHidden
        let keyboardTemp: Bool = keyboardActionView.isHidden

        // set new state based on env vars
        normalActionView.isHidden = keyboardUp ? true : !actionViewActive
        keyboardActionView.isHidden = keyboardUp ? !actionViewActive : true

        // DEBUG
        print("[AFTER]\nnormalActionView.isHidden: \(normalActionView.isHidden)\nkeyboardActionView.isHidden: \(keyboardActionView.isHidden)\nkeyboardUp: \(keyboardUp)\nactionViewActive: \(actionViewActive)")

        // animate opacity changes
        if normalActionView.isHidden != normalTemp {
            let targetAlpha: CGFloat = normalTemp ? CGFloat(1) : CGFloat(0)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: actionViewAnimationDuration / 2) {
                self.normalActionView.alpha = targetAlpha
            }
        }

        if keyboardActionView.isHidden != keyboardTemp {
            let targetAlpha: CGFloat = keyboardTemp ? CGFloat(1) : CGFloat(0)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: actionViewAnimationDuration / 2) {
                self.keyboardActionView.alpha = targetAlpha
            }
        }
    }
```

and the action called by the `UIBarButton` (this issue concerns when the button title is 'back'):

```swift
// back/cancel button action
    @IBAction func cancel(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if sender.title == "Cancel" {
            // cancel ongoing request if there is one
            if let request = ongoingRequest {
                if !request.isFinished {
                    request.cancel()
                }
            }

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "cancel_unwindFromNewPostView", sender: self)
        } else {
            // reset post type to default (general)
            postType = .general

            // set actionViewActive bool to set visibility going forwards
            actionViewActive = true

            // hide datePicker
            self.datePickerView.isHidden = true

            actionViewAnimationDuration = 0.35
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("animateActionViewChange"), object: nil)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35) {
                // layout
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }

            // revert button text to 'cancel'
            cancelButton.title = "Cancel"
        }
    }
```

Here is the output of the debugging flag before the 'back' button is hit:

```
[BEFORE]
normalActionView.isHidden: false
keyboardActionView.isHidden: true
keyboardUp: true
actionViewActive: true
[AFTER]
normalActionView.isHidden: true
keyboardActionView.isHidden: false
keyboardUp: true
actionViewActive: true
```

after:

```
[BEFORE]
normalActionView.isHidden: true
keyboardActionView.isHidden: true
keyboardUp: false
actionViewActive: true
[AFTER]
normalActionView.isHidden: true
keyboardActionView.isHidden: true
keyboardUp: false
actionViewActive: true
```

As you can see above, the `isHidden` property of the normal action view is not changing, even though it is being set to 'false'. I originally thought this was because a reference was being lost somewhere (though I thought that would result in a nil reference, which I don't have), so I made the references to `normalActionView` and `keyboardActionView` strong. This did not fix the problem, obviously, so I put the changes to `isHidden` in a method called by a notification to ensure it was always on the same thread (which it is, I checked by printing the current thread, it is always main), but that did not help either.

Comment: Hi @Jai, Are you sure the animateActionViewChange function is called? Maybe you're not doing it in the main thread? Use this in animateActionViewChange function DispatchQueue.main.async { (codes in animateActionViewChange function) }

Comment: @EmreCiftci Yes, it is definitely being called, that's where those debug flags are being printed. It is also always being called in the main thread, I printed `Thread.current` during runtime and it consistently put out main even when the error occurred. Also did try using `DispatchQueue.main.async` which did not fix it :(

Comment: `isHidden` is cumulative, so, for example, if you set it `true` twice in a row, you would need to set it `false` twice. I usually use a check for the opposite value before setting. e.g. `if view.isHidden == false { view.isHidden = true }`

Comment: @Chris Wow, you are an absolute lifesaver, it worked! There is absolutely no chance I'd have found that on my own. Repost as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution! Gotta say, I'm scratching my head a bit at why they implemented this as a counter, and why none of the documentation mentions that .

Comment: @Jai No problem - glad it helped. I only learned it when I was in a situation similar to yours and an experienced developer told me. Posting as an answer now...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`isHidden` behaves as though it is cumulative. For example, if you set it to `true` twice in a row, you would need to set it to `false` twice.

I usually use a check for the opposite value before setting a value.

```
if view.isHidden == false {
    view.isHidden = true 
}
```

---

**Edit**

As mentioned by [Yoel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9472805/yoel-jimenez-del-valle) in the comments, you can use `view.isHidden.toggle()`.

However, sometimes you need to be certain of setting it to a particular value, which the technique above will allow.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this insight. It's astonishing to me that the Apple documentation does not mention this behaviour.

Comment: @JeffreyFulton I agree - I don’t even know if it’s a bug or due to the internal workings of UIKit.

Comment: Man... After 12 years of developing apps I still feel like a babe in the woods. Thanks!

Comment: @MaciekCzarnik Thanks. There's always something new to learn eh?!

Comment: This does not seem to be true, testing this reflects that you can set a view's isHIdden property to true as many times as you want but once you set false once, it will be false.

Comment: Also there is isHidden.toggle() that no matter what you  make it would change to Rhee other state

Comment: @YoelJimenezdelvalle True, though sometimes you need to set a Boolean to a defined value rather than toggling, depending on the behaviour you need.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you bind uiview animation to keyboard notifications ? Is that a required part of your application UI ? I think you can animate your view after a button pressed. Because it's highly difficult to catch the exact keyboard animation speed together working with any view. What I mean is that keyboard closes fast while notification center tries to catch and animate view.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. the animation is actually working fine with keyboard show/hide animations, and the issue here is unrelated to the keyboard, it only breaks when called by the button action, everything else animates properly.